# Find characters and replace

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to replace this '.'  '@'  '?' to string BAD Character in Column 'D' with Highlighted in color Red, but i am missing something in this,  some one please assist.
Thanks.

```
Sub Finding()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="BAD Character", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("D2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. You can use the below code to loop thru bad characters.

```
Sub Finding()

    Dim badChar As String, str_bad As String
    badChar = ".@"

    For i = 1 To Len(badChar)
        str_bad = Mid(badChar, i, 1)
        Columns(4).Replace What:=str_bad, Replacement:="BAD Character", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[**Getting wildcards to work in find and replace function in VBA macro**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438684/getting-wildcards-to-work-in-find-and-replace-function-in-vba-macro-for-microsof)